# Why is count not taken as global value? (local variable 'count' referenced before assignment)

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to use count value inside a function and I am getting an error "local variable 'count' referenced before assignment" and I cannot use count=0 inside a function as it is recursive. I have also tried to keep global by defining count outside but it gives a syntax error. Please someone explain to me what is wrong and how to fix this code?

My code is as follows :

```
s=["abc","asd"]
d=""
count=0
def func():
     if(count==len(s)):
           exit(0)
     else:
        for i in s:
            print(i[count])
     count=count+1
     func()

func()
```

Also Tried  to keep global and I get Invalid syntax

```
s=["abc","asd"]
d=""
global count=0
def func():
     if(count==len(s)):
           exit(0)
     else:
        for i in s:
            print(i[count])
     count=count+1
     func()

func()
```

Comment: You must declare the variable ``global`` *in each scope that writes to it*. Add ``global count`` directly after the line ``def func():``. However, you should strongly consider to do this using function parameters instead of globals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare count as global inside the function like this:

```
s=["abc","asd"]
d=""
count=0
def func():
     global count
     if(count==len(s)):
           exit(0)
     else:
        for i in s:
            print(i[count])
     count=count+1
     func()

func()
```